# NSFetchResultController: Only Initial Load shows no data in the tableViewController's table

Tags: nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have:
@interface CMainTableViewController : UITableViewController

In that class I have an NSFetchResultController.

I have the following separate data manager class:
DB_ManagerSingleton
    //Here I have a UIManagedDocument that creates the DB/persistent store

To open my persistent store I do the following from my DB_ManagerSingleton class:

UIManagedDocument *fileDB = [[UIManagedDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:url];

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:self.fileDB.fileURL.path] != TRUE)
{
    [self.fileDB saveToURL:self.fileDB.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success)
     {
         [self completeDBSetup:success];
     }];
}//End if
else if(self.fileDB.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed)
{
    [self.fileDB openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success)
     {
         [self completeDBSetup:success];
     }];
}//End else if
else if(self.fileDB.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal)
{
    [self   completeDBSetup:TRUE];  
}//End else if
```

The completeDBSetup places 4 NSManageObjects into the NSManagedObjectContext and notifies the registered observers of the success that the persistent store was opened:

```
if([CLevelFactory createLevels] == TRUE)
    [self.fileDB.managedObjectContext save:&error];

for(id<DB_StateNotification> observer in self.arrNotificationDelegates)
{
    if(observer != nil)
        [observer DB_StateChange:self.isDBSetup];
}//End for loop
```

Now, in this case the observer is my TableViewController class. Within this class I have implemented all the methods in the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate and the implementation is copied exactly from the Coredata books example.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Listings/Classes_RootViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405-Classes_RootViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_14

The way I set up my tableView controller in the DB_StateChange method from above is as follows:

```
self.fetchResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
            managedObjectContext:dbMgr.fileDB.managedObjectContext
            sectionNameKeyPath:@"levelID"
                cacheName:nil];

self.fetchResultController.delegate = self;

NSError *error = nil;
self.bQuerierYourData = [self.fetchResultController performFetch:&error];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.fetchResultController fetchedObjects];

    //NOTE: I ALWAYS have a count greater than 0. Even on the first run.
if(fetchedObjects.count > 0)
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Now the issue is this:
  The very first time my application launches I get squat in my table view. I get a fetchedObjects.count of 4 - which is what I expect, but not'a in the table view.  Now, without touching anything. Not inserting, updating, or deleting anything in the persistent store, I just quick the application. In this case hitting the stop button on the debugger. When I go ahead and restart the app, everything comes in beautifully. I don't insert data every time the app starts, I test and if the data already exists, I just move on without inserting any data.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?